# How to update a zero-based index array in ko.observableArray

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, knockout.js

I'm a new programmer for knockout.
Here's a question about ko.observableArray while practicing.
I give an zero-based index array for initial data that will show with JSON while clicking button.
But when I try to update any value from input field but I cannot get the new JSON after clicking button.

And I think the problem is that there's no index in my array.How can I get the new JSON after clicking

```js
function ViewModel(inputs){  
  this.inputs = ko.observableArray(inputs);
  
  this.getData = function(){      
    this.jsonData(ko.toJSON(this.inputs));
  };
  
  this.jsonData = ko.observable('');
};
 
 
var initialData =  [ 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'etc' ];

var viewModel = new ViewModel(initialData);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
    <li>
        The current item is: <input type='text' data-bind="value: $data"></b>
    </li>
    
</ul>
<textarea rows='5' cols='60'  data-bind='value: jsonData'> </textarea>
<button data-bind='click: getData'>get Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing due to $index you can't get this updated JSON

if you add key value pair in "initialData"  you will get updated JSON data

Here blow working code :

```
function ViewModel(inputs) {
    this.inputs = ko.observableArray(inputs);

    this.getData = function () {
        this.jsonData(ko.toJSON(this.inputs));
    };

    this.jsonData = ko.observable('');
};


var initialData = [{ name: 'Jan' }, { name: 'Feb' }, { name: 'Mar' }, { name: 'etc' }];

var viewModel = new ViewModel(initialData);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


<ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
    <li>
        The current item is: <input type='text' data-bind="value: name"><br />
    </li>
</ul>
<textarea rows='5' cols='60' data-bind='value: jsonData'> </textarea>
<button data-bind='click: getData'>get Data</button>
```

Comment: So, that means I can only put dictionary-type in the array, but not only value?